# How to store a data in NFC Storage Element of android device?

Tags: phonegap-plugins, nfc, ndef

Is there any ways, I can store some data in NFC storage element of android device using some special phonegap plugin? I understand, we can read/write nfc tag and can transfer the same from a android device to another android device using Chariot Solution phonegap-nfc plugin ( https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc ). I need to know, is there any plugin for storing some data in nfc android device, Please advice! Expecting any sort of suggestions and comments. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ways, but cryptographically protected, so you'll need permission from whoever is controlling the Secure Element (I am assuming that by "NFC storage element of android device" you mean the secure chip connected to the NFC frontend and antenna). The Secure Element is the same kind of chip as the ones used in smart cards (not a plain NFC tag), so you will need to know the keys to access it. They are usually very tightly controlled by the phone manufacturer.
Other phones do not have Secure Elements themselves, but connect NFC to their SIM card, which then becomes the Secure Element: in that case, keys are controlled by the mobile network operator.

Standards to access the Secure Element from the rest of the phone are published by the [SIM Alliance](http://simalliance.org/se/se-technical-releases/simalliance-open-mobile-api-archive/).

Comment: Thanks @mictter, fan of you. I understand we can store data without using "Secure Element", using HCE (Host Card Emulation). Do we have any such plugin that uses "Card Emulation" method to store data in NFC and the same can be transferred to other device?

Comment: I don't know of any such plugin, but I know very little about HCE (I'm more in the Secure Element field :). If you don't need the extra security provided by the SE, I guess you can use the general Android storage space...

Comment: Like @mictter says, it is basically impossible to access the secure element.

After you read data from the NFC tag, you could store the data on the device. Use local storage or a database.

I don't think that Host Card Emulation will help you here. HCE is for emulating a smart card app in software instead of running it on the secure element. If you want to try HCE, I've written a Cordova HCE plugin https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-hce.